# Slider2D for 2 parameters

Tags: manipulate, slider

I don't understand how to make a and b be controlled via Slider2D at the same time (abscissa - a, ordinate - b). The hyperbola should change depending on these parameters. I am attaching the code:

```
Manipulate[Column[{
Show[
{
 Graphics[{Blue, PointSize -> 0.02, 
   Point[{a Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]], b Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]]}]}],
 ContourPlot [(x Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]])/a - (y Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]])/b ==
    1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Purple]],
 
 ContourPlot [(x/a)^2 - (y/b)^2 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]],
 
 ContourPlot [(x/a)^2 - (y/b)^2 == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]],
 Graphics[{Yellow, PointSize -> 0.02, 
   Point[{a/(Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] - Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]]), b/(
     Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] - Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]])}]}],
 Graphics[{Pink, PointSize -> 0.02, 
   Point[{a/(
     Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] + Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]]), -(b/(
      Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] + Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]]))}]}],
 Graphics[{Orange, PointSize -> 0.02, Point[{0, 0}]}]
 },
 PlotRange -> 10, ImageSize -> 500],
 N[Abs[(a/(
    Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] - 
     Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]])*(-(b/(
      Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] + Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]])))) - (b/(
    Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] - Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]])*a/(
    Cosh[\[CurlyPhi]] + Sinh[\[CurlyPhi]]))], 15]}],
 {a, 2, 10},
 {b, 1, 10},
 {\[CurlyPhi], -2 Pi, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: `Manipulate[
 With[{a = p[[1]], b = p[[2]]},
 ...<your code here>...  ],
 {{p, {2, 1}}, {0, 0}, {10, 10}}]`? Or `{{p, {1, 2}, "{a,b}"}, {1, 2}, {10, 10}}`

Comment: Thank you very much! :)))